# two symbols for a single label in legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working on a spatial plan where I'm supposed to have two states - the existing one and the future one. I have always worked with separate maps - a single map for a single state. But I was wondering is it possible to put those two states together, i.e. to have two symbols in legend for one label - one on the left side of label and one symbol on the right side. 
So far, I have one solution - to make two legends with appropriate symbols, put those legends close enough each other and turn off one of labels. But, is there a simpler way to do this?
I hope you understand my question.
Greets!

Here's an image of this problem.[image: Sorry about cyrillic, I did this map a hurry, cyrillic is official language in my country. Title "Existing state" is a part of one legend, and title "Plan" is in another legend in which I turned off label and put it close enough so it looks like it is all one legend.]

Comment: Can you include a screen capture showing what the end result should look like?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to attach an image in a comment. I'm new around here, and i am trying to manage it. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: Attach an image by editing your question (Edit button).

Answer (score 1):

For final refinements of the maps legend, I usually convert my legend to graphic. Of course, you then loose the link with your data set, but you can do anything you want with your symbol (like copy-pasting a symbol, changing its color and placing it where you want). If I understand your question, setting the symbol of a layer that is not displayed on you map for coherence with another map, this should also help you. Once you've converted your legend to graphic, you can ungroup the elements until you modify exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 because converting legend to graphics is the best way I can see to do this